# Show modal once per visit

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, show, fadeout

I know this question is asked many times before, but I can't still find any solution to my 'problem' to show my modal only one time per visit. I've tried also many different (cookie) scripts but nothing works in combination with the existing script.
Many, many Thanks!

HTML

```html
<div id="MyPopup" class="overlay">
  <div class="autopop">
    <a class="close" href="#MyPopup">&times;</a>
    <div class="a-content">
      Some content goes here.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
.overlay::before,
.overlay .autopop {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
}
.overlay::before {
  content: "";
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  display: block;
  z-index: 99990
}
.overlay .autopop {
  width: 30%;
  height: 70%;
  margin: auto;
  font: 18px/1.5em Open Sans;
  background: #ff9933;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 15px 0 #000;
  z-index: 99999;
  transition: all 3s ease-in-out;
}
.overlay:target::before {
  display: none;
}
.overlay:target .autopop {
  top: -200%;
  right: -200%;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.autopop .a-content {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
.autopop .close {
  top: 0;
  right: 15px;
  font: 800 30px Open Sans;
  color: #fff !important;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  position: absolute;
}
```

JQUERY (to start popup with a delay}

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#MyPopup").hide(0).delay(7000).fadeIn(0)}
);
```

Comment: You don't appear to be using cookies at all in your jQuery example.

Comment: A cookie is the way to do this, so you should show that attempt.

Comment: I know, I tried using some cookies before and don't know which cookie 'fits'.

Comment: You can use html5 local storage which is better than old cookies trick.

Comment: As mentioned by others, use cookies [MDN document.cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The full answer for the `cookie` option is:

1. Once you shows the popup, add a `cookie` to the browser.
2. In each time the, check if the browser has this `cookie`.

You can't see the result here because of technic reason (the iframe of the preview is setted as sanbox iframe) so you can see it [here](http://output.jsbin.com/zazewu).

**Note**: for cross browser support it's better to use `cookie` instead of `localStorage`.

```js
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
  var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}

function getCookie(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
  }
  return "";
}

var cookie = getCookie('shown');
if (!cookie) {
  showPopup();
}

function showPopup() {
  setCookie('shown', 'true', 365);
  document.querySelector('#MyPopup').style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
#MyPopup {
  display:none;  
}
```

```html
<div id="MyPopup" class="overlay">
  <div class="autopop">
    <a class="close" href="#MyPopup">&times;</a>
    <div class="a-content">
      Some content goes here.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Mosh for your answer,
I add the cookie script into my page, but it doesn't seem to work.
Refreshing the page will popup the div again.
Setting the div in CSS at 'display:none' has no effect.

Comment: My Pleasure ;) It was answer your question?

Comment: Yes, it was answer my question ;-)
I think the problem is putting it on the right place in my HTMlL file and maybe it finally works.

Comment: OK then ;) Please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer so it will help to other people.. (You can [upvote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow) too ;))

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `localstorage`?

Example code:

```
if (localStorage.getItem('IsModalShown').toString() != 'true') 
{
   showModal();
   localStorage.setItem('IsModalShown',true);
}
```